# Tracking eCommerce transactions geographically in Google Analytics Universal

Tags: google-analytics, geolocation

I've done a complete overhaul of our site and had to move our eCommerce transaction posting from the typical JavaScript calls of *ga.js* on our front-end to direct purchase processing on our back-end, for technical reasons.  I was able to accomplish this using their shiny new [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).  This seems to be functioning correctly, but I noticed that there seem to be no [parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ecomm) available for keeping track of city/state/country.

Upon further investigation, I found that even the new *analytics.js* appears to be phasing out this geographic functionality, as the new [analytics.js Ecommerce transaction calls](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs) no longer contain parameters for city/state/country.  This is problematic, because we use the *Audience -> Geo -> Location* eCommerce conversions quite a bit to track our progress internationally.  Everything right now is just defaulting to the U.S.

Has anyone had experience with the new Universal upgrade in this regard?  I haven't found any documentation that indicates that this functionality is being phased out, short of the subtle hint that it's no longer in the JavaScript calls.  They may have moved to a different location and I may just have missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't geographic information associated per session. Not directly with an ecommerce transaction? Wouldn't Analytics create the session (visit) and gather ecommerce data and associate it with that session? Have you tried viewing your profile in Analytics Explorer http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Here's what I used for an older site pre Universal

ga:medium,ga:country

ga:transactionRevenue